# Duplicate sources.list error while sudo apt-get update

Tags: ubuntu, rabbitmq, apt-get, rabbitmqctl

I was installing rabbitMQ , it get installed properly but while update i got below warnings. 
I am also not able to enable rabbitmq-management plugin.

1. Reading package lists... Done W: Duplicate sources.list entry
   http://www.rabbitmq.com/debian/ testing/main amd64 Packages
   (/var/lib/apt/lists/www.rabbitmq.com_debian_dists_testing_main_binary-amd64_Packages)
2. W: Duplicate sources.list entry http://www.rabbitmq.com/debian/
   testing/main i386 Packages
   (/var/lib/apt/lists/www.rabbitmq.com_debian_dists_testing_main_binary-i386_Packages)

Answer (score 0):

```
Duplicate sources.list:
```

means that "Your sources.list really has duplicate entries."

Check you source list, and also see:
https://askubuntu.com/questions/120621/how-to-fix-duplicate-sources-list-entry

> I am also not able to enable rabbitmq-management plugin.

What do you mean? do you have errors ? Can you post it ?